# Is the LIMIT statement useful for reducing the query costs in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am testing out some things in the BigQuery's sandbox and one thing that I wonder is is there a purpose in using LIMIT in your SQL queries so that you reduce your costs.

Specifically on the Chicago taxi trips dataset this query that fetches only the cost of the trip for 500 records

```
SELECT trip_total 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips` 
LIMIT 500
```

> Query complete (0.3 sec elapsed, 1.4 GB processed)

And the one that goes over the whole dataset

```
SELECT trip_total 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
```

> Query complete (9.6 sec elapsed, 1.4 GB processed)

Will both end up costing me the same.

The time for the execution goes down a lot (9.1 sec vs 0.3 sec - both timed with disabled caching)

So if you are on the flat-rate pricing it might make sense to decrease computing time so you can allocate your resources to different tasks.

But is there really a point in using the LIMIT statement in terms of saving up on query costs in the on-demand plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The LIMIT statement saves time to print fewer records in the UI. If you want to reduce query costs, my first suggestion is to use [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) based on a date.